# Nothing happens when I right click on computer and click on properties

Tags: windows-7

I got a strange problem:
When I click on the computer (or network) icon on my desktop, and then click on the "properties"-entry in the context menu, nothing happens.
Maybe somebody has an idea what could be wrong?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to be a problem with a DLL which is not correctly registered anymore.

Here's a thread about it:
http://www.joejoe.org/forum/topic/18364-no-such-interface-supported-error/page__st__20

Re-registering the DLL's solved this strange problem ;)

Answer (score 1):

This might help. Use regedit and go to :
`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer`.

Create a DWORD named NoPropertiesMyComputer and set it to 0.
The changes take effect after a restart or logoff.

A detailed example is found [here](http://www.liutilities.com/products/registrybooster/tweaklibrary/tweaks/10920/) that sets the value to 1. Just remember to set it at the end to 0 instead of 1.

Comment: Eww eww eww Liutilities!

Comment: Thanks for this advice, I just tried it, but without success :(

Comment: @ben: The only other advice I have to give is [How To Perform a Startup Repair in Windows 7](http://pcsupport.about.com/od/toolsofthetrade/ss/windows-7-startup-repair.htm). This will refresh Windows while keeping your installed products (backup first).

Comment: It will certainly be simpler to just access this thru Control Panel / System, until the time comes to reinstall Windows in the future.